# Most memory-efficient way of holding base64 data in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, md5, base64

Suppose you have a MD5 hash encoded in base64.  Then each
character needs only 6 bits to store each character in the
resultant 22-byte string (excluding the ending '==').  Thus, each
base64 md5 hash can shrink down to 6*22 = 132 bits, which
requires 25% less memory space compared to the original 8*22=176
bits string.

Is there any Python module or function that lets you store base64
data in the way described above?

Comment: Since base64 is an ASCII encoding of binary, why not just store it directly as binary? Wouldn't the be the most efficient way? (Have a look at http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-base64.html - specifically the `decodestring` function.)

Comment: I am fully aware that I can just generate a md5 digest specifically for the example in the question, which is just 16 bytes long. But I'm not limiting this question to md5. It applies to all base64-encoded data.

Comment: By the way, that documentation page is probably for the wrong version of Python...it was just one of the first results I got on Google, and I didn't check it properly.

Comment: @otz: Why does it matter whether it's an MD5 digest or not? **All** base64-encoded data should be convertible to a string of bytes (granted, not all of the bytes will be printable, and I don't know how Python handles NUL characters in strings - or whether it has a special byte buffer type that can handle them properly).

Comment: @David Thanks. I didn't realize there was a function that decodes base64 data into binary. You'd still have to add the padding at the end (if you deleted it) like <code>base64.decodestring(md5_encode('hello')+'==')</code>. But it does what I wanted to do.

Comment: @David Can you post an "answer" saying "use decodestring", so that I can accept it and mark this question as 'solved'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David gave an answer that works on all base64 strings.

Just use

```
base64.decodestring
```

in base64 module. That is,

```
import base64
binary = base64.decodestring(base64_string)
```

is a more memory efficient representation of the original base64 string.  If you
are truncating trailing '==' in your base64 md5, use it like

```
base64.decodestring(md5+'==')
```

Answer (score 8):

The most efficient way to store base64 encoded data is to decode it and store it as binary. base64 is a transport encoding - there's no sense in storing data in it, especially in memory, unless you have a compelling reason otherwise.

Also, nitpick: The output of a hash function is not a hex string - that's just a common representation. The output of a hash function is some number of bytes of binary data. If you're using the md5, sha, or hashlib modules, for example, you don't need to encode it as anything in the first place - just call `.digest()` instead of `.hexdigest()` on the hash object.

Answer (score 5):

Simply decode the base64 data to binary:

```
>>> b64 = "COIC09jwcwjiciOEIWIUNIUNE9832iun"
>>> len(b64)
32
>>> b = b64.decode("base64")
>>> b
'\x08\xe2\x02\xd3\xd8\xf0s\x08\xe2r#\x84!b\x144\x85\r\x13\xdf7\xda+\xa7'
>>> len(b)
24
```

Answer (score 4):

> "store base64 data"

Don't.

Do. Not. Store. Base64. Data.

Base64 is built by encoding **something** to make it bigger.

Store the original **something**.  Never store the base64 encoding of **something**.